# Kubernetes Autoscale Nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a project on Kubernetes and only 1 pod is running on each node and it has to be like that. How can I autoscale the nodes I want to build? So how can I create a new node when the load on the node increases. I am using AWS and Azure.

Comment: "So how can I create a new node when the load on the node increases." mean is how can i start new server instance(or virtual server)?

Comment: Yes correct. I m talking about how to auto create nodes (not pods) I know this is a little weird, but i need it.

Comment: Why only run one pod on each node? This isn't exactly the way kubernetes is supposed to be used.

Comment: Because i have to use `network_mode: host`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you want to run a pod per node. We have separate groups of applications and each group runs on certain node groups. We use [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) to scale down/up nodes based on usage. We then use taints and tolerations on pods/nodes for each group of application. Cluster auto scaler will scale up nodes for the specific application group is pods are in pending status.

added below portion -

One useful article about scaling in kubernetes is [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/kubernetes-autoscaling-101-cluster-autoscaler-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-and-vertical-pod-2a441d9ad231). You can read about Cluster Autoscaler (CA) as well.

Comment: Because I have to use `network_mode: host`. I need to forward port range, so i need it. As I understand your reply, I can do that with cluster autoscaler

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this with ClusterAutoscaler:

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler